# How to fix Throughput 5xx error request heroku

Tags: reactjs, web, heroku

I deployed 6 months ago a small website using [heroku platform](https://signup.heroku.com/?c=70130000000NeLCAA0&gclid=CjwKCAiAvonyBRB7EiwAadauqUYZuGnwjSr9TnrlY8ONaAdW691f2pkVjkbbzcnTF5oUBfExwFz9HRoClwMQAvD_BwE). 
Everything was going normally until today the website seems to be down. I investigated a little bit the possible causes and came across [this official source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics):

> The Throughput plot displays the number of requests broken down by
>   HTTP status code (1XX, 2XX, 3XX, 4XX and 5XX). The throughput (which
>   can be toggled between RPS and RPM in the metrics preferences) is also
>   displayed for each status code in the legend. Requests that result in
>   a 5XX status code are considered failed requests.

I am not sure what is means.

Also I investigate more and went to the dashboard of the project and clicked on **Metrics**

[image: heroku]

What I saw was the following exchange requests, the first print screen was for the past 48-24 hours:

[image: failed-requests]

The one below was instead for the past 24 hours:

[image: 24-hours]

What is going on?

If anyone has been through this problem, please point to the right direction as I have no idea what to do as this never happened to me.

Comment: You need to check the Heroku logs. Chances are the 500 errors indicate an error in your application.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks so much for reading the question. How do I check the logs on Heroku? Also when you say in my application, are you referring to the actual code?

Comment: Also it was working fine for 6 months, but today all of a sudden everything is offline. How could that be possible?

Comment: I think I found the logs. Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/58gxsVS.png) useful to understand something?

Comment: You can see there that `POST` requests to the URL `/update` are failing with a 500 error. You need to start debugging those requests.