# MongoDB - JavaScript : Web application stopped working because MongoDB is full?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku

I have a very small example website as test. I am recording vessels latitude/longitude and additional information and send them **continuously** to my `MongoDB`, which seems to be full now as you can see below. Also it says: `Displaying documents 1 - 20 of 2984034` and there is a maximum limit (set by me) as shown and that has been reached:

[image: limit]

**The error** I am getting is a `5XX` error from the `Heroku` platform which means `requests failed`, now I wonder if that happens because my external database `MongoDB` is basically full?
Could that happen?

[image: error]

After a careful debugging my application fails on the following API route:

```
app.route("/update").post(scowlogController.createNewScowLog);
```

Below is an extract from the `Heroku` logs. In addition, if that could be useful, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178469/how-to-fix-throughput-5xx-error-request-heroku) is the initial post and below a more precise print screen:

[image: status]

Below a small extract of the code **scowlog_controller.js**, you will see some parts I coded outputting a warning like `return res.status(500).send(err);` in case something happens.

But, again, could that stop a whole site to work??:

```
exports.listAllScowLogs = (req, res) => {
  ScowLog.find({}, (err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(task);
  });
};


exports.createNewScowLog = (req, res) => {
  let newScowLog = new ScowLog(req.body);
  let scow = scowController.registerScowById(newScowLog.scow);


  var ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
  if (ip){
    var list = ip.split(",");
    ip = list[list.length-1];
  } else {
    ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  }
  newScowLog.ip = ip;

  newScowLog.save((err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.status(201).json({"Status":"Success"});
  });
};

function chunk (arr, len) {

  var chunks = [],
      i = 0,
      n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}

exports.createNewScowLogs = (req, res) => {

  var ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
  if (ip){
    var list = ip.split(",");
    ip = list[list.length-1];
  } else {
    ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  }

  req.body.forEach((scw) => {
    scw.ip = ip;
  });

  let newlogs = chunk(req.body, 400);

  let promises = [];
  newlogs.forEach((logs) => {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ScowLog.insertMany(logs, (err) => {
        if(err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        else {
          return resolve("Success");
        }
      });
    }));
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
    return res.status(201).json({"Status":"Success"});
  }).catch((err) => {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  });
};
exports.readScowLog = (req, res) => {
  ScowLog.findById(req.params.scowid, (err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(task);
  });
};

exports.deleteScowLogsOlderThanOneWeek = (req, res) => {
  var lastweek = moment().add(-7, 'days');
  ScowLog.remove({ created: { "$lt": lastweek } }, (err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(200).json(task);
  });
};
```

**What I am doing so far** is debugging as much as possible, and I resticted the problem, hopefully, to the print screens and comment I reported above.

What is happening? Could that be the problem and therefore the solution would be just to erase all the records and clean everything?

Thanks for any advice for solving this problem.

Comment: If you think the database might be the problem, check the database logs

Comment: @Joe, thanks for reading the question, how do I check the logs on MongoDB? I have been also trying to understand if there is a free limit beyond which everything stops working?

Comment: @Joe, also if that is important I [set a limit](https://imgur.com/fqIfYmF) as you can see and I wonder if that is the problem?

Comment: And therefore I wonder if heroku if failing requests because of that?

Comment: not sure how Heroku manages mongodb, if they are setting a cap on your storage size, that may be it

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. MongoDB was full and caused a 5XX error of failed requests to Heroku servers, which cause my whole app to go down. The solution is: either erase the whole collection (but back up the data if you need them) or to increase the storage amount for the cluster (but this would entail a modification of the subscription). Either way will solve the problem!! In any case, lesson learned, an additional check for the storage should be foreseen. :)